# Extend / Append to Terraform template_file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

Using terraform, I'd like to see if there's a way — with the template rendering system — to define a `template_file` in a terraform module (base template) and then "extend" or "append" to the rendering in the instantiation rather than replaced.

I can currently define the `template_file` in either location, but would like to know if I can build upon the module's template on a per-instance basis. The specific use case is for userdata on AWS EC2s which vary slightly from instance type to instance type.

Thank you,
Neurax

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up finding out.

In the module. Define an a `template_file` for the base template. Then define an `output` (for example named `"module_template"`) whose value is equal to the rendered version of the `template_file`.

Then in the instantiation, define another `template_file` with a var equal to something like `mod_temp = "${module.module_name.module_template}"`, and then in the `template_file`, reference that variable where necessary with `${mod_temp}`.

I was thinking about trying to escape values in the "super template" so that maybe they would get interpolated during the "sub template's" rendering. Initial tests have not been successful.